# stringByAppendingString not concatenating

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to take an array of strings and take each item and put it into a string format.  I wrote a method to do this as I need to concatenate the listed array values into another string.  For some reason I cannot get the array values to list properly, a blank string is returned.

```
- (NSString*)listParameters:(NSArray*)params
{
NSString *outputList = @"";

if (params) {
    for (int i=0; i<[params count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[params objectAtIndex:i]);
        [outputList stringByAppendingString:[params objectAtIndex:i]];
        if (i < ([params count] - 1)) {
            [outputList stringByAppendingString:@", "];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"outputList: %@", outputList);
return outputList;
}
```

The first log statement properly returns a string (so there is definitely a string in the array), but the second log statement only returns "outputList: ".

I tried making outputList start as more than just an empty string which didn't work.  I also tried assigning `[params objectAtIndex:i]` to a string then appending it, didn't work either.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I cannot get it to work.

How can I get this array of strings to print into a single string separated by commas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `[outputList stringByAppendingString:[params objectAtIndex:i]]` and `[outputList stringByAppendingString:@", "]` back to `outputList`.

It would be better still if you were using an instance of NSMutableString for `outputList` instead, as you're going to create a lot of autoreleased objects in that loop otherwise.

Comment: Took your suggesting and made outputList an `NSMutableString` instead, works perfectly, thanks! (will accept when 10 minutes has passed)

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to use a [NSMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead with its appendString method. NSString is immutable.

```
- (NSString*)listParameters:(NSArray*)params
{
    NSMutableString *outputList = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    if (params) {
        for (int i=0; i<[params count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[params objectAtIndex:i]);
            [outputList appendString:[params objectAtIndex:i]];
            if (i < ([params count] - 1)) {
                [outputList appendString:@", "];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"outputList: %@", outputList);
    return outputList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
outputList = [outputList stringByAppendingString:@", "];
```

as stringByAppendingString works by returning a new String